# jQuery mobile css and js not applied to the content loaded with .load()

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

so..here is the scenario
i have a page with data-role="page" and one header container and footer divs - normal jquery mobile page structure.

Now in my content div i have two divs. out of which in one of the div i'm loading some other content dynamically having buttons and textboxes with data-role specified.

now the problem:

while loading new page in the div the controls are not displayed as mobile controls instead they look like normal html controls. This may be due to as they are loading after the dom is ready they are not getting the jqm js and css.

following is the page structure.

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquerymobile.css" type="text/css" />
     <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div  data-role="page">
     <div data-role="header">
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
     <div id="static_content"></div> // no problem to this.
     <div id="dynamic_content"></div> // dynamic content used .load() - no jqm css loaded :(
     </div>  
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put your content loading into the jQuery mobile event structure. See here for details:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

I used the 'pagecreate' event to modify the content before it is enhanced by jquery, like this:

```
  obj_out.add "$('div').live('pagecreate',function(event){" & vbNewLine
  obj_out.add " $('.jsvisible').show();" & vbNewline
  obj_out.add " $('.jshidden').hide();" & vbNewline
  obj_out.add " $('.nojs').removeClass('nojs');" & vbNewline
  obj_out.add "});" & vbNewline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the page widget constructor after you have loaded your dynamic content

```
 $("div[data-role='page']").page('destroy').page();
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include the page destroy command. Its been edited.

Comment: Hey @Alex, just following up, did that .page('destroy').page() work for you?

Comment: sorry json it didn't. meanwhile i figure out new way. i used $.get method instead of .load() and used trigger('create') instead .page().